# how to generate payload from csv feeder using Gatling scala

Tags: arrays, csv, gatling

I would like to generate a payload for the POST request that should generate the payload like the below, that should append order numbers at the end and add it to selection list to generate the payload as below. Can you please advise how to generate the payload below for each of the employee record from csv feeder file attached above?

is there a way to stream thru order number list in the csv file above to generate the payload below?

```
  csv file content
    data.csv
    empNo, orderNo
    e12345,[49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,57]
    e23456,[52,51,53,50,37,36,38]
    e37765,[96,95,94,88,87,50,49,42,62,54,14-16,51,53,52,55,41,63]
    e47899,[96,95,94,93,92,91,90,89,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,47,46,48,45,44,43,42,41]
    e59090,[95,96,94,93,50,87,86,88,14-16]
    e69000,[96,95,94,88,87,26,25,43,44,50,10]
    e72453,[96,95,94,93,49,50,51,63,62,61,56,55,54,53,52,64,65,92,91,90,88,87,86,89]
    
   payload selection list example:
    http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/49
    
    POST URL: http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/order?employeeId=12345
    
    
    Payload needed:
    
 
 "submittedAt": "2023-02-08T20:27:33.144109-06:00",        
 "allowSameMonth": false,       
 "allowConsecutiveMonths": true,       
 "selections": [ 
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/49",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/50",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/51",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/52",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/53",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/54",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/55",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/56",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/41",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/42",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/43",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/44",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/45",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/46",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/47",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/48",
            "http://localhost:8080/order/00000-00000-00000/base-order/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/order-no/57"
            ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
private static String generatePayload(String empNo, String orderNo) {
  // for you to implement, this is standard Java code, not related to Gatling
  return payload;
}

// see https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#stringbody

// with a function payload
http("name").post("/")
  .body(StringBody(session -> {
     String empNo = session.getString("empNo");
     String orderNo = session.getString("orderNo");
     return generatePayload(empNo, orderNo);
  }));
```

Comment: Hi Stephane, Can you please confirm if i have to define csv file line below,    val order = csv("data/data.csv").circular.  and then use feed(order) before reading the value using session variable like below? 

// with a function payload

http("name").post("/")
  .body(StringBody(session -> {
     String empNo = session.getString("empNo");
     String orderNo = session.getString("orderNo");
     return generatePayload(empNo, orderNo);
  }));                                                          
and I am using scala, not java,

Comment: and orderNo is an array [49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,57], and not the string, can you please explain why you mentioned as a string?

Comment: and Can you please help me with the scala snippet to iterate thru orderNo list to generate the payload?

Comment: Hi @Stéphane LANDELLE, came across InputSreamBody https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/. wondering ig Gatling InputStreamBody helps to handle the above scenario i mentioned? or is inputStreamBody for a different purpose? can you please confirm?

Comment: orderNo is a column of a CSV file so the feeder is going to generate it as a single String. It's your job to parse your custom format (probably into a String) and generate your payload. It's really just simple Java code.

Comment: InputStreamBody has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Hi @Stéphane LANDELLE, ok, Thank you, Can you also please confirm if csv file transform is applicable here? found the below snippet. Please confirm if csv transform is related to the scenario that is being discussed here ..  
csv("myFile.csv").transform {
  case ("attributeThatShouldBeAnInt", string) => string.toInt
}



https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/feeder/

just a note, I am using scala, not java.